# how to reload OCaml modules in utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

Is it possible reload modules in OCaml's [utop](https://github.com/diml/utop)?

My development workflow goes something like this when playing around with OCaml code:

First, open up a file `example.ml` in Vim and hack on it.  Switch to another terminal and run `utop`.  From within `utop`, load the code with the directive `#use "example.ml";;`.

Go back to Vim and make some changes in the code.  After changing the code, I want to play around with the new changes.  Go back to `utop` and rerun the directive `#use "example.ml"`.

It would be nice if there were a  `#reload` directive that would reload all previously loaded modules, but there doesn't appear to be.  **Is there some way to easily reload all previously loaded modules?**

Ideally this would work similarly to GHCi's [`:reload`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:reload) command.

Comment: Assuming that the modules don't change between two runs. Is it possible to pass object files to utop? For example, you have a file tree.ml that you compiled to tree.cma (or tree.cmo), can you load the tree module with the command line "utop tree.cma". If so, you would just have to restart utop with the right options. The default is that it might not work that great inside emacs.

Comment: In the greeting message from `#use "topfind";;`, it says: `... Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded ...`

Comment: You could put all your `#use`s in a `.ml` file and `#use` it each time you want to reload everything in it

Answer (score 2):

At the time this question was asked, I believe [dune](https://github.com/ocaml/dune#dune---a-composable-build-system) had not yet established itself as *the* build system  for OCaml. Using dune, you can simply launch a utop instance with locally defined libraries loaded (as explained [here](https://github.com/ocaml/dune/blob/main/doc/usage.rst#launching-the-toplevel-repl)) by doing :

```sh
$ dune utop <dir> -- <args>
```

> Where `<dir>` is a directory under which dune will search (recursively)
> for all libraries that will be loaded